# UITableView dequeueReusableCell duplicates constraints

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, nslayoutconstraint

Using swift, I have a `UITableView` and custom `UITableViewCells`.  After each cell is initialized I call a method ( `layoutViews()` ) to apply the appropriate constraints ( `NSLayoutConstraint.activate([...]` ).  One constraint, a labels leading anchor, is dynamic based on the row and results in somewhat of an indented look between parent and child records.

Example :

```
Parent
    Child
Parent
Parent
    Child
        Grandchild
    Child
    Child
```

As I scroll the constraints get confused and result in duplicate constraints on the same cell

> **Error: Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints... Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint).**

Most of the time no indentation is performed when it should be.

I have tried to deactivate the previous constraints, remove previous constraints, and remove all views from the superview.  I got various results, but none were correct.

I just want the indentation to match the `CGFloat` value I am providing in the `getIndentaion()` function.

As requested, here is the relevant code (abbreviated form, of course).

In the UIViewController:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! CustomCell
    cell.setIndentation(2)
    cell.layoutViews()
    return cell
}
```

In the CustomCell:

```
func getIndentation() -> CGFloat {
    return 5 + ((indentation ?? 0) * 15)
}

func layoutViews() {
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        messageLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: messageBackground.leadingAnchor, constant: getIndentation())
    ])
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please show the relevant code; you should not add constraints when he cell is reused, only when it is initialised e.g. in `awakeFromNib`

Comment: Thank you for the comment, @Paulw11.  That's the problem I'm having.  The indentation is performed based on values not provided in the dequeueReusableCell statement.  How should I implement dynamic indentations based on a numeric value provided after the cell is initialized?

Comment: You need to add a constraint once and then update its `constant` rather than adding a constraint every time the cell is laid out.

Comment: Thank you.  That worked.  That is exactly what I needed.  Please post that as an answer so I can select it as the best response.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, @Paulw11.  The following solution worked:

In the UIViewController:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! CustomCell
    cell.setIndentation(2)
    return cell
}
```

In the CustomCell:

```
var indentationConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!

func layoutViews() {
    indentationConstraint = messageLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: messageBackground.leadingAnchor, constant: 5)

    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        indentationConstraint
        ])
    }
}

func setIndentation(_ indentation: CGFloat) {
    let totalIndentation: CGFloat = 5 + (indentation * 15)
    indentationConstraint.constant = totalIndentation
    messageLabel.layoutIfNeeded()
}
```